# Multiple joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can I join multiple tables together using MySQL?  I have 3 separate tables.

**Projects**

```
ID    Project Name
1     Big Project #1
```

**Projects Contract Managers**

```
ID    Project Id    Contract Manager Id
1     1             11
```

**Contract Managers**

```
ID    Name
11    John Smith
26    Bill Smith
```

I want to join the 3 tables above to get a list of projects along with contract manager names.

Comment: Note that the id column in `Projects Contract Managers` appears to serve no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just two `INNER JOIN`s seems to be enough :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Projects Contract Managers` pcm
JOIN `Contract Managers` cm ON pcm.`Contract Manager Id` = cm.`ID`
JOIN `Projects` p ON pcm.`Project Id` = p.`ID`
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possiblity from the first suggested I always feel reads better. I think the engine would optimize to the same execution plan. You would want to confirm with EXPLAIN if the tables are large and you are worried about performance.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Projects Contract Managers` a,
     `Contract Managers` b,
     `Projects` c
WHERE a.`Contract Manager Id` = b.`ID`
      a.`Project Id` = c.`ID`
```

Comment: I disagree. I don't think SO should be promoting the use of archaic syntax.

Comment: Before we had JOINs, we had commas

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have, I assume that projects can have more than one contractor and contractors can be a part of more than one project, with that in mind, here is mysql code to create the tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project` VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `contractors` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `project_contractors` (
  `pid` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cid` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the query with the join to return all records:

```
SELECT *
FROM projects AS p
JOIN project_contractors AS pc
ON p.id = pc.pid
JOIN contractors AS c
ON pc.cid = c.id;
```

You may need to add some where clauses and order by if you wish, but if you want to return everything that will do it.

Here is some for the project_contractors table:

```
pid cid
1   2
1   1
2   3
3   4
```

for the contractors table:

```
id  NAME
1   john
2   mike
3   dave
4   steve
```

for the projects table:

```
id  project
1   FIRST project
2   SECOND project
3   third project
```

and the result of the query:

```
id  project pid cid id  NAME
1   FIRST project   1   2   2   mike
1   FIRST project   1   1   1   john
2   SECOND project  2   3   3   dave
3   third project   3   4   4   steve
```

I think this will cover what you were looking for, good luck!

Comment: I just used the current tables that he had and wrote the query for him, that's what he asked for.